# ASP CSS file stopped working

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-studio

When I apply a change on a CSS file, the changes doesn't go through (although it was working before)!

If I see the style applied to the element on IE11 in troubleshoot mode, I see the old settings instead of seeing the new ones.

The structure of the site actually is the structure that VS-2015 Community created by default:

```
MyWebsite
    Content
        mycss.css
```

The header of the master page is as follows:

```
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<% Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"; %>
<% Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); %>
<% Response.Expires = -1; %>
    <meta />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - Credits and Returns or Replacements.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/mycss.css">

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    <style type="text/css">
        .body-content {
            height: 549px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
```

The piece of html is below:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="dateFrom" runat="server" CssClass="another calendar"></asp:Calendar>
<asp:Calendar ID="dateTo" runat="server" CssClass="another"></asp:Calendar>
```

So for example, if I have a class called .another{width:20%;} and I change it to 15%, the change does not get applied to the webpage.
If I check the style applied into the webpage (IE11 pressing F12) I see the old 20% instead of the new 15%.
While in troubleshoot mode in IE11, if I click on the link "mycss.css" next to the applied style, I see the "another" with the old value. The url of the file is "/Content/mycss.css".

I also tried searching all the files named "mycss.css". I found a bunch into internet explorer temp files and proceeded to delete all temp files with ccleaner. I knew that I was not going to help but I had to try.

I even published the css file to the deployed site without success.

At this point, I do not know where the css file with the old setting is. It should exist somewhere keeping the old values but I cannot find it and must of all, why VS is creating and keeping a file with the same name in a different path that I can not see??? !!!

There is a configuration option that I am missing, which creates this kind of behavior?

Regardless of what I have tried, the problem persists. Could somebody tell me please, what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try refreshing the cache. I think in IE it's ctrl F5. In chrome ctrl R to reload css.

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast. I just did it as you suggested but unfortunately it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's you are experiencing some caching issues. I prefer using chromes developer tools to debug CSS and JS issues. If your interested, in chrome, right click on the element you and to check and select 'inspect element'. I think that if you reload the page with the developer tools still open it will automatically refresh he cache. Also with chrome, as you edit your CSS file in VS, you will see the change automatic lol upload in the browser. Hope this helps.

Comment: Helpful Tidbit....if you are using IE, then you can go to tools -->Delete Browsing History and this will clear the cache.  There is a way to disable caching but I am not sure right off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. In the company the only browser that we can use is IE11, as the CRM is compatible only with IE. I am struggling to have the authorization from the manager. As soon as I install it, I will go back with the results.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, it runs on Chrome. After that, I reinstalled IE (turned off and On in Control Panel/Programs/Turn Windows Features on or off) and it is working again.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and support.